# In Unity3D,How do I enter Chinese on the TextField in a UIElement panel?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I switched the input method to Chinese, but when entering text, instead of a box for selecting words, the English letters I input (Chinese Pinyin) appear directly in the Text Field.

But, I can paste Chinese into Text Field.

The version of my Unity3D is 2019.3.11.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Keyboard.current.SetImeEnabled(true)` to enable the native IME input.

The relevant documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Keyboard.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_Keyboard_SetIMEEnabled_System_Boolean_

Comment: It worked. I use it with the event `onTextInput`. Don't use the event `onIMECompositionChange` , this event can't get the character input by SouGou IME (but it worked on Microsoft IME).